# Excluding names in one list from second list [r]

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have two lists:

```
ls1 = list("a","b","c","d","e")
ls2 = list("b","e")
```

How can I create a third list `ls3` which will contain elements that are in `ls1` but are not in `ls2`?

In this example `ls3` should contain "a", "c" and "d".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need this to work with lists? Or is your data really in a vector?

Comment: I get one list of file names using list.files and the other list from an excel file. Not really sure if I can make it work with vectors. I'm planning to use lapply + read.csv over ls3.

Comment: `class(list.files())` seems to indicate it returns a character vector, not a list. You can `lapply` over vectors just as easily as lists.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about this if I had vectors instead of lists? Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the same way. But in other cases, it can be very different. It's more of a warning just to be careful with your data types. Don't call something a list in R if it's not a list. That has a very specific meaning and behavior. I knew `setdiff` worked with vectors, but I didn't know it worked with lists too until I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `setdiff()`?

```
ls1 = list("a","b","c","d","e")
ls2 = list("b","e")
setdiff(ls1, ls2)
```

That returns `list("a","c","d")` just as you desire.